# Centering an absolutely positioned child to a parent with no positioning via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm in sort of a tricky situation. Basically I have this scrollable horizontal nav that has an `overflow-x: auto`. The nav has links with dropdowns that appear on hover.

The overflow prevents the dropdown from appearing without setting its position to `absolute`. The caveat is that I can no longer align my dropdown to the link container. This is more evident when using a trackpad and scroll horizontally while hovering over a nav link. The dropdown will misalign. What would be the way to keep the dropdown anchored horizontally with its parent inline via javascript? I'm not object to using jQuery.

My first attempt was to take half the width of the parent, apply that as the left margin negatively and apply a left positioning of 50%. Since it's not anchored it'll automatically center to the global parent.

```js
$('.nav-link-container').each(function() {
  $(this).find('.dropdown').css({
    left: '50%',
    marginLeft: -(this.offsetWidth / 2),
  })
})
```

```css
#nav {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.nav-link-container {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.nav-link-container:last-of-type {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.nav-link-container:hover .dropdown {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="nav">
  <div class="nav-link-container">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <div>Dropdown Link 1</div>
      <div>Dropdown Link 2</div>
      <div>Dropdown Link 3</div>
      <div>Dropdown Link 4</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="nav-link-container">
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <div>Dropdown Link 1</div>
      <div>Dropdown Link 2</div>
      <div>Dropdown Link 3</div>
      <div>Dropdown Link 4</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="nav-link-container">
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <div>Dropdown Link 1</div>
      <div>Dropdown Link 2</div>
      <div>Dropdown Link 3</div>
      <div>Dropdown Link 4</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="nav-link-container">
    <a href="#">Link 4</a>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <div>Dropdown Link 1</div>
      <div>Dropdown Link 2</div>
      <div>Dropdown Link 3</div>
      <div>Dropdown Link 4</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="nav-link-container">
    <a href="#">Link 5</a>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <div>Dropdown Link 1</div>
      <div>Dropdown Link 2</div>
      <div>Dropdown Link 3</div>
      <div>Dropdown Link 4</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="nav-link-container">
    <a href="#">Link 6</a>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <div>Dropdown Link 1</div>
      <div>Dropdown Link 2</div>
      <div>Dropdown Link 3</div>
      <div>Dropdown Link 4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Given that the position of the dropdown depends on the scroll amount of the container, you won't be able to apply a static position on page load. You'll need to determine the correct position using the offset *at time of hover*, or something of the sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use JS (jQuery) for this. Use the [`.hover()`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) event handler to show/hide the dropdown when the link is hovered.

In the handler in function get the [`.offset()`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) - the `top` and `left` of `.nav-link-container` in relation to the document. Use that and and the height of `.nav-link-container` to set the offset of the relevant `.dropdown`, and show the dropdown.

In the handler out reset the dropdown's offset and hide it.

You can add a [`.scroll()`](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/) event handler to update the offset when `#nav` scrolls.

```js
var $nav = $('#nav')

function setDropdownOffset($link, $dropdown) {
  var offset = $link.offset()

  return $dropdown.offset({
    top: offset.top + $link.height(),
    left: offset.left
  })
}

$('.nav-link-container').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this)
  var $dropdown = $this.find('.dropdown')

  $(this).hover(function() {
      var offset = $this.offset()

      $nav.on('scroll', function() {
        setDropdownOffset($this, $dropdown)
      })

      setDropdownOffset($this, $dropdown)
        .show()
    },
    function() {
      $nav.off('scroll')

      $dropdown
        .offset({
          top: 0,
          left: 0
        })
        .hide()
    })
})
```

```css
#nav {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.nav-link-container {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.nav-link-container:last-of-type {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="nav">
  <div class="nav-link-container">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <div>Dropdown Link 1</div>
      <div>Dropdown Link 2</div>
      <div>Dropdown Link 3</div>
      <div>Dropdown Link 4</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="nav-link-container">
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <div>Dropdown Link 1</div>
      <div>Dropdown Link 2</div>
      <div>Dropdown Link 3</div>
      <div>Dropdown Link 4</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="nav-link-container">
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <div>Dropdown Link 1</div>
      <div>Dropdown Link 2</div>
      <div>Dropdown Link 3</div>
      <div>Dropdown Link 4</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="nav-link-container">
    <a href="#">Link 4</a>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <div>Dropdown Link 1</div>
      <div>Dropdown Link 2</div>
      <div>Dropdown Link 3</div>
      <div>Dropdown Link 4</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="nav-link-container">
    <a href="#">Link 5</a>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <div>Dropdown Link 1</div>
      <div>Dropdown Link 2</div>
      <div>Dropdown Link 3</div>
      <div>Dropdown Link 4</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="nav-link-container">
    <a href="#">Link 6</a>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <div>Dropdown Link 1</div>
      <div>Dropdown Link 2</div>
      <div>Dropdown Link 3</div>
      <div>Dropdown Link 4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the dropdown to stay anchored to the parent while horizontally scrolling though? You'll notice it if you scroll with something like a trackpad.

Comment: @CarlEdwards You could apply the repositioning code on the `scroll` event of the container.